# Esri arcgis API v3.2 silverlight - Map gets stuck panning when clicking in the middle of a pan

Tags: c#, silverlight, arcgis, esri

I am working on a Silverlight application. I find that when I am working on an oldish PC, if I carry out a pan operation (i.e. click the mouse, drag and release), if I carry out another pan operation before the first completes the map seems to get stuck in pan mode - i.e. where ever I move the mouse, the map follows. I then can't get out of this mode, and the app is then impossible to use.

I have found this thread:

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2455&t=292899

raised in 2009, and this thread:

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2455&t=302383&mc=6

raised in 2010, neither of which have a solution or workaround described in them. The second thread does link to an Esri bug report which i've been advised was fixed in v2.0 of the API. However I've confirmed that I'm using v3.2 of the API everywhere.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Can you submit a new support incident at [support.esri.com](http://support.esri.com)? It's possible that you've found a new bug. Also, make sure you're using Silverlight 5.x, according to the [system requirements](https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/guide/system-requirements.htm).

Comment: We have submitted a support request, but aren't getting a terribly rapid response, so I thought I'd raise it here just in case someone else was aware of the issue. Thanks - will follow up with Esri.

Comment: Not having much luck getting advice on how to stop it from happening, so I'm wondering if anyone can provide some advice on how to stop the user from being able to pan a second time, before the first pan operation is complete? i.e. the user should be able to click and drag, but once they release the mouse button mouse input should be ignored until the new extent has been fully redrawn?